# Centering the flex-element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have such layout

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  background: #0d1717;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  width: 360px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar .title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Fairview;
  color: #fcfcfc;
}
```

```html
<header class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <!-- content -->      
  </div>
  <span class="title">Summary</span>
</header>
```

How do I place the .title in the center of the block .navbar with flexbox? But at the same time, so that the .navbar-nav is left.

Comment: Did you try `text-align: center;` or `margin: 0 auto;`?

Comment: justify-content: center;

Comment: Ofc, but these methods don't work in this case.

Comment: Do you want to center horizontally?

Comment: @DudinVadim Look at the solution.

Comment: Check the dupe link ... and here how to use it on your code https://jsfiddle.net/xbn1tyu8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `justify-content:center` . **justify-content** is used to `align items horizontally` while align-items is used for aligning them vertically.

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  background: #0d1717;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar .title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Fairview;
  color: #fcfcfc;
}
```

```html
<header class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-nav">
  </div>
  <span class="title">Summary</span>
</header>
```

**Using margin:auto on the child element to align horizontally:**

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  background: #0d1717;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar .title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Fairview;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-nav">
  </div>
  <span class="title">Summary</span>
</header>
```

`When another content is present as well in the navbar.` You can make use of **absolute and relative position and transform the position** of title:

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  background: #0d1717;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position:relative;
  color:white;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  width: 360px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar .title {
  position:absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Fairview;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<header class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-nav">
  </div>
  <span class="title">Summary</span>
</header>
```

Comment: But in this case the .navbar-nav is also centered, and it must remain on the left.

Comment: @DudinVadim justify-content doesn't affect the navbar  but the child tags inside it. Or you can make use of margin:0 auto on the child element to center. I updated it.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the code of the .navbar-nav

.navbar .navbar-nav {
    width: 360px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

Comment: @DudinVadim Update it then :)

Comment: i updated the task. :)

Comment: @DudinVadim I added the 3rd solution which doesn't take anything else in consideration and just centers the title.